# Setting Cache-Control metadata via gsutils does not update response headers

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gcloud, cache-control, gsutil, max-age

When setting the cache-control metadata key via the gsutils command:

`gsutil -m setmeta -h "Cache-Control:public, max-age=14400" 'gs://my-bucket/style.css'`

I verify that the metadata is updated correctly using another gsutils command:

`gsutil stat 'gs://my-bucket/style.css'`

However, when accessing this object via `curl --head` the value is not update

```
content-type: text/css
age: 232
cache-control: public,max-age=3600
```

I am expecting for the max-age of the cache-control property to be set to the value specified in the gsutil command which is 14400.

Comment: Andre - did you wait 3600 seconds after updating the metadata before checking? If you attempted the `curl` command sooner than that you could be seeing the cached oldervalue.

Comment: Yes I waited over an hour and don't see the updated value in the response headers. This is some of the metadata I see when doing `gsutil stat`:
**Storage class:          MULTI_REGIONAL
Cache-Control:          public, max-age=14400
Content-Length:         62207**

Comment: That `gsutil stat` command is sending an HTTP `GET`, while the`curl` command is sending an HTTP `HEAD`. I wonder whether there is a proxy in your path that incorrectly handles HTTP `HEAD`. Are you running the `curl` command from behind a corporate firewall or via a proxy?

Comment: I was, I just tried it with the VPN off and even on another laptop and still see the same result unfortunately.

Comment: Hello @MikeSchwartz , when doing the `curl --HEAD` I am requesting the object via a CDN url; whereas for the `gsutil` I am using the path to the object. Does there need to be some configuration on the CDN to be able to use the object metadata for caching?

Comment: Unfortunately I have not worked with the CDN. I found this page: https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/using-ttl-overrides
which makes me wonder if you have a TTL override configured.

Comment: I was not using the correct cache-mode on the bucket, solution was in updating the cache-mode to USE_ORIGIN_HEADERS. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not using the correct cache-mode on the bucket, solution was in updating the cache-mode to USE_ORIGIN_HEADERS. Thank you!